# Excel vba loop through 01.Month and 01.01. given min and max days

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a min and a max dates stored As `Date` objects. I try to iterate between them in a for cycle.

```
Sub dateTest()
    Dim min_date As Date
    Dim max_date As Date

    min_date = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Cells(22, 5).value
    max_date = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Cells(23, 5).value

    Dim currentDate As Date
    For currentDate = min_date To max_date
        MsgBox (currentDate)
    Next
End Sub
```

However the cycle displays every day of each month, while I only need the first day of each month and (in another cycle) only the first of January. How would I accomplish this?

I tried

```
For currentDate = min_date To max_date Step 7
            MsgBox (currentDate)
Next
```

But it only allows to make a days as a step, so this code displays a day per week, rather than a day per month or a day per year.

Comment: Sorry, can't make sense of your last paragraph when comparing it to your loop. The code obviously steps in increments of 1 week between 2 arbitrary dates. Mind clarifying a bit?

Comment: @Excelosaurus: You're right, I tested the given code and it does indeed increment by 1 week per cycle.

Comment: Do you need the first day of each MONTH or WEEK?

Comment: @Excelosaurus, I apologize for the confusion I caused. It indeed displays a day per week beween the dates, it's something I tried myself trying to get it to do what I want (first day of  a month and first of January a year), however it didn't work since `Step` only takes a day-step, and I can't simply do a 30 day step, since for each month it's different. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will cleanly loop from the first day of the month containing min_date, to the first day of the month containing max_date:

```
Sub dateTest()
    Dim min_date As Date
    Dim max_date As Date
    Dim firstOfMonth As Date
    Dim lastFirstOfMonth As Date

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup")
        min_date = .Cells(22, 5).Value
        max_date = .Cells(23, 5).Value
    End With

    firstOfMonth = DateSerial(Year(min_date), Month(min_date), 1)
    lastFirstOfMonth = DateSerial(Year(max_date), Month(max_date), 1)

    Do While firstOfMonth <= lastFirstOfMonth
        MsgBox firstOfMonth
        firstOfMonth = DateAdd("m", 1, firstOfMonth)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: If min_date isn't the first of the month, he might want the first of the next month as the first date - see my answer for a function to calculate that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a message box to show the first day of each month, you can check if the date is 1 (the first of each month).

```
For currentdate = min_date To max_date
    If Day(my_date) = 1 Then
        MsgBox (my_date)
    Else
        'Do Nothing
    End If
Next
```

This returns a message box for the first of each month.

To display the first of January, check the month as well.

```
For currentdate = min_date To max_date
    If Month(currentdate) = 1 Then
        If Day(currentdate) = 1 Then
            MsgBox (currentdate)
        End If
    Else
        'Do Nothing
    End If
Next
```

Comment: That's not a very efficient way to do it - unnecessary looping.

Comment: As a follow up, `DateAdd` took 0.35 seconds to print each first of the month between November 1st, 1810 to November 6th, 2017. Looping through each day took 0.61 seconds. So you're not wrong, it is less efficient than `DateAdd`.

Answer (score 1):

The [DateAdd](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php) function should help:

Assuming your min date is always on the first of the month:

```
Dim currentDate As Date
currentDate = min_date
Do Until currentDate >= max_date
    currentDate = DateAdd("m", 1, currentDate) ' Adds 1 month to the date
    ' Use DateAdd("yyyy", 1, currentDate) for adding 1 year.
    MsgBox currentDate 
Loop
```

If your min date is not on the first day of the month, replace the line "currentDate = min_date" with

```
currentDate = GetNextFirstDayOfMonth(min_date)
```

and add the following Function:

```
Function GetNextFirstDayOfMonth(d)
    If Day(d) > 1 Then
       GetNextFirstDayOfMonth = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d), 1)
    Else
       GetNextFirstDayOfMonth = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d) - 1, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Fun facts: Using Nov 6th, 1810 to Nov 6th, 2017 and using the `GetNextFirstDayofMonth` function, it took 0.61 seconds to print the first of each month within the range.

Comment: Haha, what a coincidence!

Comment: No joke, 0.61 seconds for Excelosaurus's solution as well.

Comment: You're fast to dismiss the message boxes. Jokes aside, it might be the "printing" that's taking the bulk of the time; are you using Debug.Print?